# How to use RKSwipeBetweenViewControllers without root view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to use RKSwipeBetweenViewControllers in my project.
I followed tutorial and github example source code of that it is working fine.
here is link [RKSwipeBetweenViewControllers github link](https://github.com/cwRichardKim/RKSwipeBetweenViewControllers)

but I don't want to use pageviewcontroller as root view controller or Home Screen.

I want that controller on Next Screen. or My First screen is other screen. after that screen I want to use RKSwipeBetweenViewControllers. but I don't get idea how to do that.

Appreciate for help!!!!

Comment: okay then set your first controller as root view controller, after that u can navigate to your pageviewcontroller

Comment: but where can I create Pageviewcontroller like appdelegate in current controller. @Shan